# How to Multiply and sum nested dictionary in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary, nested

I have a Dictionary in C# with this structure :

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, double>> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, double>>
        {
            {
                0, new Dictionary<string, double>
                {
                    { "eat",0.15 },
                    { "food", 0.16 }
                }
            },
            {
                1, new Dictionary<string, double>
                {
                    { "eat",0.32 },
                    { "food", 0.2 }
                }
            },
        };
```

I want to sum and multiply eat in other dictionary,

```
0.15 * 0.32 + 0.16 * 0.2
```

what should i do to code this in c# with foreach?

thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a LINQ solution:

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, double>> dict = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, double>>() {
    {0,new Dictionary<string, double> { { "eat",0.15 }, { "food", 0.16 } } },
    {1,new Dictionary<string, double> { { "eat",0.32 }, { "food", 0.2 } } }
};

double eat = dict.Values.Select(x => x["eat"]).Aggregate((x, y) => x * y);
double food = dict.Values.Select(x => x["food"]).Aggregate((x, y) => x * y);

double result = eat + food;
```

**EDIT**

Here is a more compact and universal solution:

```
var result = dict.SelectMany(x => x.Value)
                 .GroupBy(x => x.Key, y => y.Value, (Key, Value) => new { Value })
                 .Sum(x => x.Value.Aggregate((a, b) => a * b));
```

**result** = `0.08`

[DEMO HERE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ziyJoa)

Comment: You could get this in 1 line, if you grouped and sum

Comment: @TheGeneral I'm just trying to, but if you have a solution you could post yours

Comment: @TheGeneral I just posted a new soultion could you check it out

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, double>>() {
                  {0, new Dictionary<string, double>() {{"eat", 0.15}, {"food", 0.16}}}, 
                  {1, new Dictionary<string, double>() {{"eat", 0.32}, {"food", 0.2}}}};

var total = dict.Values.SelectMany(x => x)                // Flatten
                .GroupBy(x => x.Key)                      // Group by key
                .Sum(x => x.Select(y => y.Value)          // sum list of sub values
                           .Aggregate((y, z) => y * z));  // multiply

Console.WriteLine(total);
```

**Output**

```
0.08
```

[**Full Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qfpxKK)

Comment: Your solution is a little bit more elegant then mine, so I will upvote +1

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem using foreach loop and some linq at the end as following:

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, double>> data = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, double>>()
        {
            {
                0,new Dictionary<string, double>(){{ "eat" , 0.15 },{ "food" , 0.16} }
            },
            {
                1,new Dictionary<string, double>(){{ "eat" , 0.32 },{ "food" , 0.2 } }
            }
        };
        Dictionary<string, double> finalResultDic = new Dictionary<string, double>();
        foreach (var entry in data)
        {
            foreach (var subEntry in entry.Value)
            {
                if (finalResultDic.ContainsKey(subEntry.Key))
                {
                    finalResultDic[subEntry.Key] *= subEntry.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    finalResultDic.Add(subEntry.Key, subEntry.Value);
                }
            }
        }
        var finalResult = finalResultDic.Sum(dic => dic.Value);
```

Answer (score -3):

Try following :

```
            Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, double>> dict = new Dictionary<int,Dictionary<string,double>>() {
               {0, new Dictionary<string,double>() {{"eat" , 0.15}, {"food" , 0.16}}}, 
               {1, new Dictionary<string,double>(){{"eat", 0.32},{"food", 0.2}}}
            };

            double total = dict.Select(x => x.Value.Select(y => x.Key * y.Value).Sum()).Sum();
```

Comment: The result is wrong, you are getting `0.52` istead of `0.08`